# Which are the most Relevant Performance Parameters / Measures for a Web Application

Tags: performance, iis, webserver

We are re-implementing(yes from scratch) a web application which is currently in production. We have decided to start doing some performance tests on the new app, to get some early information of the capabilities.

As the old application is currently in production and has a good performance we would like to extract some performance parameters, and then use this parameters as a reference or base goal of the performance of the new application.

Which do you think are the most relevant performance parameters we should be obtaining from the current  production application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Determine what pages are used the most.
2. Measure a latency histogram for the total time it takes to answer the request. Don't just measure the mean, measure a histogram.

From the histogram you can see how many % of requests have which latency in milliseconds. You can choose to key performance indicators by takes the values for 50% and 95%. This will tell you the average latency and the worst latency (for the worst 10% of requests).

Those two numbers alone will bring you great confidence regarding the experience your users will have.

Throughput does not matter for users, but for capacity planning.

I also recommend that you track the performance values over time and review them twice a year.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need an HTTP client, there is [weighttp](http://gwan.com/en_apachebench_httperf.html#weighttp), a multi-threaded client written by the guys from Lighttpd.

It has the same syntax used by ApacheBench, but weighttp lets you use several client worker threads (AB is single-threaded so it cannot saturate a modern SMP Web server).

The answer of "usr" is valid, but you can as well record the minnimum, average and maximum latencies (that's useful to see in which range they play). Here is a [public-domain C program](http://gwan.com/source/ab.c) to automate all this on a given concurrency range.

Disclamer: I am involved in the development of this project.